# Create two Google Calendar events from one Google Form submission

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api, google-forms

I'm trying to create a Team On-call Scheduler using Google Forms and Google Calendar. Each Team has the option to have both a Primary and a Secondary on-call. So far I've been able to successfully get the code to place the primary option into Google Calendar but I'm unable to figure out how to get the code to place the secondary into the Calendar if selected. I've searched for answer from others and unable to find anything or maybe I just don't understand as I am very new to coding. Thank you in advance to anyone that may be able to help.

I should be clear and give credit to a gentleman by the name of Jesse Spevack (http://www.jessespevack.com/blog/2016/2/9/turn-a-google-form-response-into-a-calendar-event) who provided the base.

Here is my code so far...

```js
//Load the Moment.js library once.
var moment = Moment.load();

var GLOBAL = {
  //the id of the form we will use to create calendar events 
  formId : "xxxxx",
  
  //the id of the calendar we will create events on
  calendarId : "xxxx",
  
  //a mapping of form item titles to sections of the calendar event
  formMap : {
    eventTitle: "Team Primary On-call",
    startTime : "Primary start date/time",
    endTime: "Primary end date/time",
    description: "Primary On-call Contact",
  },
}

function onFormSubmit() {
  var eventObject = getFormResponse();
  var event = createCalendarEvent(eventObject);
}

function getFormResponse() {
  // Get a form object by opening the form using the
  // form id stored in the GLOBAL variable object
  var form = FormApp.openById(GLOBAL.formId),
      //Get all responses from the form. 
      //This method returns an array of form responses
      responses = form.getResponses(),
      //find the length of the responses array
      length = responses.length,
      //find the index of the most recent form response
      //since arrays are zero indexed, the last response 
      //is the total number of responses minus one
      lastResponse = responses[length-1],
      //get an array of responses to every question item 
      //within the form for which the respondent provided an answer
      itemResponses = lastResponse.getItemResponses(),
      //create an empty object to store data from the last 
      //form response
      //that will be used to create a calendar event
      eventObject = {};
  //Loop through each item response in the item response array
  for (var i = 0, x = itemResponses.length; i<x; i++) {
    //Get the title of the form item being iterated on
    var thisItem = itemResponses[i].getItem().getTitle(),
        //get the submitted response to the form item being
        //iterated on
        thisResponse = itemResponses[i].getResponse();
    //based on the form question title, map the response of the 
    //item being iterated on into our eventObject variable
    //use the GLOBAL variable formMap sub object to match 
    //form question titles to property keys in the event object
    switch (thisItem) {
      case GLOBAL.formMap.eventTitle:
        eventObject.title = thisResponse;
        break;
      case GLOBAL.formMap.startTime:
        eventObject.startTime = thisResponse;
        break;
      case GLOBAL.formMap.endTime:
        eventObject.endTime = thisResponse;
        break; 
      case GLOBAL.formMap.description:
        eventObject.description = thisResponse;
        break;
    } 
  }
  return eventObject;
}

function createCalendarEvent(eventObject) {
  //Get a calendar object by opening the calendar using the
  //calendar id stored in the GLOBAL variable object
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(GLOBAL.calendarId),
      //The title for the event that will be created
      title = eventObject.title,
      //The start time and date of the event that will be created
      startTime = moment(eventObject.startTime).toDate(),
      //The end time and date of the event that will be created
      endTime = moment(eventObject.endTime).toDate();
  //an options object containing the description and guest list
  //for the event that will be created
  var options = {
    description : eventObject.description,
  };
  try {
    //create a calendar event with given title, start time,
    //end time, and description and guests stored in an 
    //options argument
    var event = calendar.createEvent(title, startTime, 
                                     endTime, options)
    } catch (e) {
      //delete the guest property from the options variable, 
      //as an invalid email address with cause this method to 
      //throw an error.
      delete options.guests
      //create the event without including the guest
      var event = calendar.createEvent(title, startTime, 
                                       endTime, options)
      }
  return event;   
}
```

Comment: You may not want to use an Add-on, but if that were an acceptable solution for you, you could try:  [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/data-director-for-forms/bjlicikmbfbjckkgemmiddonmigijpbj?authuser=0)

Comment: Thanks for the input, unfortunately, I can't use an add-on as they are blocked by our Google Apps Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Change this function:

```
function onFormSubmit() {
  var eventObject = getFormResponse();
  var event = createCalendarEvent(eventObject);
}
```

To:

```
function onFormSubmit() {
  var eventObject, calendarTwoID;

  eventObject = getFormResponse();

  calendarTwoID = 'Put the ID of the second calendar here';

  createCalendarEvent(eventObject);//Create first event
  createCalendarEvent(eventObject, calendarTwoID);//Create second event
}
```

Change the `createCalendarEvent` function to:

```
function createCalendarEvent(eventObject, calendarID) {
  //Get a calendar object by opening the calendar using the
  //calendar id stored in the GLOBAL variable object
  var calendar;

  if (calendarID) {//If ID is passed in
    calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarID);//use the passed in ID
  } else {//Otherwise use the global ID
    calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(GLOBAL.calendarId);
  }

  //The title for the event that will be created
  var title = eventObject.title,
  //The start time and date of the event that will be created
  startTime = moment(eventObject.startTime).toDate(),
  //The end time and date of the event that will be created
  endTime = moment(eventObject.endTime).toDate();
```

Comment: Hello Sandy, thanks for your input and this is an idea I've considered creating two calendars one for primary and the other for secondary. However I was really hoping to put it all one calendar for ease of use. Any idea how that might be done?